# NetBeans IDE Keyboard Shortcut for Line Wrap Option

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I use NetBeans IDE 7.0, and I am grateful that it has a "Line Wrap" option, but I don't usually want it on.  I would like to have a keyboard shortcut so I can enabled on the fly as needed.  Under Tools->Options->Keymap I am unable to find a Line Wrap action.  Am I overlooking it?  Is there a way to add actions?

Comment: I am also unable to find a line wrap action. Fairy annoying, when I'm reading PHP code that sometimes is 100 - 200 chars wide and I really want to toggle line wrapping on off.

Comment: Wow! 298 chars on one line, why are they doing that :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported. But you can vote for such a feature http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189657

Comment: I don't seen how to vote, but I added a comment that links to this post.

Comment: I am currently working on such a plugin. When it is stable then i will publish it in the NB update center and update the bugzilla above.

Comment: I installed your plugin, and it's great!